# List Sort Direction is always null for custom sort column in wpf datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF DataGrid with 3 columns. For the first 2 columns I want the default sorting but for the third one I want a custom sort in ascending/descending order.
I have handled the sorting event on datagrid as follows:

```
        private void ReleaseDataGrid_Sorting(object sender, DataGridSortingEventArgs e)
    {
        ListSortDirection direction = (e.Column.SortDirection != ListSortDirection.Ascending) ? ListSortDirection.Ascending : ListSortDirection.Descending;
        if (e.Column.SortMemberPath == "DisplayName")
        {
            SortStatusImg.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
            SortVersionImg.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
            SortPackageNameImg.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
            if (direction == ListSortDirection.Ascending)
            {
                SortPackageNameImg.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/Resources/sortup.png"));
            }
            else
            {
                SortPackageNameImg.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/Resources/sortdown.png"));
            }
        }
        else if (e.Column.SortMemberPath == "UserMachineStatus")
        {
            SortStatusImg.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
            SortVersionImg.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
            SortPackageNameImg.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
            if (direction == ListSortDirection.Ascending)
            {
                SortStatusImg.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/Resources/sortup.png"));
            }
            else
            {
                SortStatusImg.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/Resources/sortdown.png"));
            }
        }
        else if (e.Column.SortMemberPath == "ReleaseInfo")
        {

            DisplayReleaseList.Sort(new VersionComparerDesc());

            SortStatusImg.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
            SortVersionImg.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
            SortPackageNameImg.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
            if (direction == ListSortDirection.Ascending)
            {
                SortVersionImg.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/Resources/sortup.png"));
                DisplayReleaseList.Sort(new VersionComparer());
            }
            else
            {
                SortVersionImg.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/Resources/sortdown.png"));
                DisplayReleaseList.Sort(new VersionComparerDesc());
            }

            RefreshMediaGrid();
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

For first two columns it works fine. But for the custom sort column, it sorts once in ascending order and later no matter how many times I click on column header it does not sort at all.

When I sort by third column, the ListSortDirection is always null and hence when the control enters this method, direction always is assigned ListSortDirection.Ascending

It does not preserve the sort direction. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the `SortDirection` property of the column:

```
private void ReleaseDataGrid_Sorting(object sender, DataGridSortingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Column.SortMemberPath == "ReleaseInfo")
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        ListSortDirection direction = (e.Column.SortDirection != ListSortDirection.Ascending) ? ListSortDirection.Ascending : ListSortDirection.Descending;
        e.Column.SortDirection = direction;

        //sort according to your logic...
    }
}
```

This should make the arrow appear as expected in the column header.